# How to retrieve a column with another name in many-to-one Eloquent relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I've just started a new project in Laravel. I want it to be multi-language, so some tables have a field for each language, like:

```
Continent
 id
 en (for English)
 pt (for Portuguese)
 es (for Spanish)
```

So that:

```
1 'America', 'América', 'America'
2 'Africa', 'África', 'África'
```

Similarly, I have a "Regions" table.

My Continent model already has:

```
public function regions() {
        return $this->hasMany(Region::class);
    }
```

My goal is to rename the columns at runtime, so that I can use "Continent->name" or "Region->name", instead of "Continent->en" and "Region->en".

So far, I can achieve results this way:

**ContinentController@index**

```
public function index() {
    $lang = 'en';

    $continents = DB::table('continents')->rightJoin('regions', 'continent_id', '=', 'continents.id')->select("continents.$lang AS continent_name", "regions.$lang AS region_name")->get();

    return view('geo.continents.index', compact('continents'));
}
```

However, that brings me a table:

```
@section('content')
    @foreach ($continents as $continent)
    {{ $continent->region_name }} {{ $continent->continent_name }} 
    @endforeach
@endsection

Central America (America)
Caribbean (America)
North America (America)
South America (America)
```

I want to accomplish a similar result, but using the Eloquent style. Something like this:

`$continents = Continent::select('continents.en AS name')->with('regions')->get();`

So far, I can get the continent name as a "name" property. How do I get the region name as a "name" property like:

$continent->name;
$region->name;

Comment: Wouldn't you just do `$continent->{$lang}` and `$region->{$lang}`? You shouldn't have to do a complicated `SELECT AS`/`JOIN` etc. if you already have that.

Comment: @TimLewis: if I new it was that simple... Thanks! That works!!!

Comment: No problem! The only caveat is that you'll need to pass `$lang` to all views/functions along with `$continent` and `$region`, handle issue if `$whatever->{$lang}` is `null`, etc; but should be pretty straightforward if you keep that in mind. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You want to look into [scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/eloquent#local-scopes).

```php
// Continent.php

public function scopeRegion($query, $region)
{
        return $query->where('region', $region);
}
```

Then in your controller,

```php
Continent::region('en')->get();
```